# How do I match an empty subject line in an Outlook rule?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2011, email-filter

I would like to create a rule in Outlook (2011 for Mac) to match on a empty subject line and return a message hinting that it would be better to include an informative subject line next time. (Yes, it is a try to use a technical solution for a social problem.)

I'm not able to add a rule with "Subject", "is" and then leave the text area empty. The "OK" button is disabled until I enter something there. If I enter a space the rule doesn't match incoming e-mails with empty subject lines.

I also tried matching a specific header "Subject" "does not exist". That didn't work either. Maybe because the Subject line is included but is just the empty string.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by switching your thinking around a little to make Outlook look to see if the subject line is NOT blank.

Create a template for the message you want to send in reply. Then create a rule which will use the exception: "subject line contains specific words". You will add single letters into the exception criteria. Vowels work best because most subject lines are going to have them in it.

*In essence, this rule will look to see if the subject line meets the criteria. If not (blank), it will reply with the template you choose.*

Here are detailed instructions: [Rule to AutoReply all correspondence without subject](http://www.officetooltips.com/outlook/tips/rule_to_autoreply_all_correspondence_without_subject.html).